# Swift to Kotlin - Extensions

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, extension-methods

I am trying to create a custom variable (fooModel) as an extension to the Android 'Activity' class.  In Swift, this was done simply as a class extension to 'UIViewController', creating the variable and then accessing it at anytime.

Here is the extension that works in Swift:

```
extension UIViewController {
    var fooModel : barFooModel? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.fooModel) as? barFooModel
        }

        set(value) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.fooModel, value, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
}
```

In Kotlin, I've done the following:

```
var Activity.fooModel: barFooModel?

get() = fooModel as barFooModel

set(value) {
    fooModel = value
}
```

This throws the following error:

> Unresolved reference: fooModel

One auto-generated solution is to import 'fooModel', but this seems incorrect and still does not solve the error.

Note: I AM able to access this variable extension via a variable adhering to the 'Activity' class, (see below for an example of how that looks), which makes this seem like it SHOULD work, I'm just missing something:

```
fun <T: Activity, M: BarFooModel> newInstance(context: Context, activityType: T, _fooModel: M): T {

        val intent = Intent(context, activityType::class.java) as T
        **intent.fooModel = _fooModel**   // intent.fooModel IS accessible, based on the extension created.

        return intent
    }
```

Am I on the right track?  What can I do to match the Swift implementation of the 'fooModel' variable extension?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should look like:

```
object AssociatedKeys {
    const val fooModel = "fooModel"
}

open class BarFooModel : Serializable

var Intent.fooModel: BarFooModel?
    get() {
        return getSerializableExtra(AssociatedKeys.fooModel) as BarFooModel?
    }
    set(value) {
        putExtra(AssociatedKeys.fooModel, value)
    }

fun <T : Activity, M : BarFooModel> newInstance(context: Context, activityType: T, _fooModel: M): Intent {

    val intent = Intent(context, activityType::class.java)
    intent.fooModel = _fooModel

    return intent
}
```

Intent may be used for storing `Associated Objects`

Comment: This appears to be working now that I've had time to implement it.  There is only 1 problem remaining:

When I call: 

intent.fooModel = _fooModel

The class is not recognizing 'fooModel' and claims it's an unresolved reference.  It suggests I import 'fooModel', but won't allow me to do so (doesn't make sense to do this regardless).  Any further ideas would be welcomed!  I will keep trying some various ideas...   Once I am able to run the code and verify this solution did in fact work, I will be sure to checkmark your response!  Thanks again.

Comment: I believe I resolved it!  I had the Intent.fooModel variable in a separate class than the newInstance function.  (This is how we built it in iOS). Apparently, Android prefers that, as you show here, everything be in the same class when working with extensions. 

Is this always the case?  Can I not create an extension in one class that applies to all others?  Perhaps if I place it inside of a custom class 'companionObject' to act as a Singleton... but, I fear I'm straying into areas I shouldn't by doing so.

Either way, thank you.  Your solution helped very much.